# Binary Search Tree toString

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble printing out a binary search tree in the format my professor wants.

His format looks like this:

```
{(12,10,13),(10,8,11),(8,6,9),(6,4,7),(4,2,5),(2,1,3),(1,*,*),(3,*,*),(5,*,*),(7,*,*),(9,*,*),(11,*,*),(13,*,*)}
```

The first number in a subset is the root node, and the left and right nodes are the left and right children. The left child then becomes the root node after a loop iterates. everything works fine until I reach where only one node exists in a subset. It just prints (1, *, *) till the end, and I can not figure out how to do it another way. Is it possible to recursively do this toString method?

My Code:

```
public String toString()
{
   if (root == null)
       return "{}";
   String str = "{";
   Node tmp = root;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {   
        if (tmp.right != null && tmp.left == null)
            str += "("+tmp.data+", "+tmp.right.data+", *)";
        if (tmp.left != null && tmp.right == null)
            str += "("+tmp.data+", "+tmp.left.data+", *)";
        if (tmp.left == null && tmp.right == null)          
            str += "("+tmp.data+", *, *)";
        else
            str += "("+tmp.data+", "+tmp.left.data+", "+tmp.right.data+")";

        if (tmp.left != null)
            tmp = tmp.left;
   }

   return str += "}";   
}
```

Comment: If the format is `(root,left,right)`, then you should flip the `*` and `tmp.right.data` in the first `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach depends how you have your objects setup, but I typically have a `Node` class that performs the recursive operations. If implemented in this fashion, you should see output like so

```
{(12,10,13),(10,8,11),(8,*,*),(11,*,*),(13,*,*)}
```

For this example, we will have a method that returns your `(data,left,right)` format on the `Node` class.

```
public class Node<T>

    protected T data;
    protected Node<T> left;
    protected Node<T> right;

    public String tuple() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(")
                .append(this.data)
                .append(",");
        sb.append(this.left == null ? "*" : this.left.data)
                .append(",");
        sb.append(this.right == null ? "*" : this.right.data)
                .append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Then, the recursive string would be implemented in the `toString` like so.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String divider = ",";

        sb.append(this.tuple()).append(divider);

        if (this.left != null) {
            sb.append(this.left).append(divider); // recurse left
        }

        if (this.right != null) {
            sb.append(this.right).append(divider); // recurse right
        }

        if (sb.length() > divider.length() - 1) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - divider.length());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, in some `BinaryTree` class, you could have

```
public class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

    protected Node<E> root;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{"
                + (root == null ? "" : String.valueOf(this.root)) +
                "}";
    }

    // other methods

}
```

Comment: I attempted your method of doing it, but I can not figure out what is wrong. For the first tuple it prints (12, 10, 13) just like it should. For the rest however it just prints out their memory location.

Comment: Also, what about this is recursive exactly, where did you call toString() inside of itself?

Comment: `sb.append(this.right)` will call `this.right.toString()`, just like `System.out.println(this.right)` would do.

Comment: And sidenote, it's actually a hashcode, not the memory location. But that's strange. Are `left` and `right` both `Node` instances?

Comment: I have a node class that is private, and it has two instance variables left and right. So I call it as node.left. I modified yours to fit my program.

Comment: Since you used this to make the accepted answer, you might up-vote this answer.

Comment: @sbowde4, that previous comment was for you.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I think you want to have all four clauses in an if-then-else structure.  At the moment, the first two cases (one child) will also execute the "else" clause.

The main problem is that you never come back to work with the right sub-tree: the only movement logic goes to the left.  Your loop executes once for each element of the tree, but your only traversal is down the left side.  You take six steps to get down to node 1, but you never backtrack to any of the right children.

I suspect that you'll want to handle this with a recursive routine, one that call itself for both the left and right branches.

Does that get you going?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is for `toString` to (almost) generate the following:

1. A `{`
2. The triple for the root node
3. A comma and `toString` for the left node, if it isn't empty
4. A comma and `toString` for the right node, if it isn't empty
5. A `}`

The only problem is that the recursive calls should *not* print the enclosing braces; I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, thank you everyone that helped. This is what I wrote in the end to recursively print the binary search tree

```
   public String toString()
   {   
       if (root == null)
           return "{}";   
       return "{"+toString(root) + "}";

   }
   private String toString(Node parent)
   {
       if (parent.left == null && parent.right == null)
           return "(" + parent.data + ", *, *)";
       else if (parent.left == null && parent.right != null)
           return "(" + parent.data + ", *,"+parent.right.data+" )" + toString(parent.right);
       else if (parent.left !=null && parent.right == null)
           return"(" + parent.data + ", "+parent.left.data+", *)"+ toString(parent.left);
       else
           return "(" + parent.data + ", "+parent.left.data+", "+parent.right.data+")" + toString(parent.left) + toString(parent.right);          

   }
```